# Get value from shared preference in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I want to get the value of locale language in my app. I'm using shared preference and I want to use the locale language value in a another page, but I don't find the way to call the value:

This is my page main.dart with :

```
    class TranslatePreferences implements ITranslatePreferences
{
  static const String _selectedLocaleKey = 'selected_locale';

  @override
  Future<Locale> getPreferredLocale() async
  {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if(!preferences.containsKey(_selectedLocaleKey)) return null;

    var locale = preferences.getString(_selectedLocaleKey);
    return localeFromString(locale);

  }


  @override
  Future savePreferredLocale(Locale locale) async
  {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await preferences.setString(_selectedLocaleKey, localeToString(locale));

  }


}
```

If I understand well I have to use the getPreferredLocale() in my other page but even I import the main.dart I can get the getPreferredLocale() in lang.dart page:

```
class lang{
string lang=TranslatePreferences.getPreferredLocale();
print(lang);

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the bottom on the `TranslatePreferences` file (outside the classs) add:

```
TranslatePreferences translatePreferences = TranslatePreferences();
```

then in the `lang` class you can use it:

```
string lang=translatePreferences.getPreferredLocale();
```

Comment: im not sure, but i think you also need to change `static const String _selectedLocaleKey...` to `String _selectedLocaleKey...`

Comment: Hi thank you, but when I want to print (lang.toString()) I get Instance of 'Future<Locale>' how I can over passe it ? thanks

Comment: I find the way to print with translatePreferences.getPreferredLocale().then(value).....